# Add element to a specific xpath using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to achieve the following.

Here's a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<database>
    <rad>
        <timeout> 45 </timeout>
    </rad>
    <tac>
        <timeout> 70 </timeout>
    </tac>    
</database>
```

1) Using XSLT I want to check if /database/rad/timeout value is greater than 30(in this case its 45), change it to 30.

2) Add new tags as follows:

```
<warnings>
  <warning>Time out of RAD changed.</warning>
</warnings>
```

So the output XML should contain the following:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <database>
        <rad>
            <timeout> 45 </timeout>
        </rad>
        <tac>
            <timeout> 70 </timeout>
        </tac>
     <warnings>
      <warning>Time out of RAD changed.</warning>
    </warnings>   
    </database>
```

There are a lot of such conditions that could be there. I was able to do the first part:-

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/database/rad/timeout">
        <timeout>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". > 30">30</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </timeout>
    </xsl:template>
        <!-- ignore text content of nodex -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However for the second part I am not sure where to start, Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "*if /database/rad/timeout value is greater than 30 ... change it to 30.*" Your output shows 45, and your XSLT makes it 100. That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rad[timeout > 30]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <timeout>100</timeout>
    </xsl:copy>
    <warnings>
        <warning>Time out of RAD changed.</warning>
    </warnings>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, although it would put the `<warnings>` element before the `<tac>` element in the output. I wonder if that's OK with the OP.

Comment: Thanks, although I wanted warnings at the end.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Actually, This might not work for me because the errors/warnings could be emitted here from multiple places and i want all of them preferable to appear like:    <warnings>
        <warning>Time out of RAD changed.</warning>   <warning>Time out of ABC changed.</warning> 
    </warnings>. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: @user2766839 I could easily move the warning to the end, by matching the `database` element instead of `rad`. However, your added remark: "*the errors/warnings could be emitted here from multiple places*" indicates that the situation is more complex than what your question would lead us to believe and I am not sure I understand it fully. Please edit your question and clarify - (add more scenarios).